# Python, I cannot change list elements from another script element

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I have been doing a sudoku solver and encounter a problem.

```
grid = [
    [7, 8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
    [6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 0, 9],
    [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 7, 8],
    [0, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 2, 6, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 9, 3, 0],
    [9, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5],
    [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
    [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0],
    [0, 4, 9, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0, 7]
]
```

I have this grid on the global scope, and this function in the same scope:

```
def solve_sudoku():
    global grid

    grid = solver.solve(grid)
```

This function calls solve function inside solver.py (I have already imported it into this script).

```
def solve(grid):
    # I do all calculations and solve it here and return grid.
    return grid
```

When I print my grid inside solver.solve function it prints the solution but when I return it into solve_sudoku function, which is in my main script, grid stays same. Nothing changes.

It's about a little mistake about passing arguments probably, I searched in internet and couldn't do it. Thanks in advance for your help..

EDIT:

Here is my code and console output. (I omit irrelevant part from the code here)

solver.py

```
# Solving algorithm
def solve(grid):
    # Scanning grid for empty square.
    for y in range(9):
        for x in range(9):
            if grid[y][x] == 0:
                for i in range(1, 10):
                    if isPossible(y, x, i, grid): #isPossible checks if that number can put on grid, position (x,y) 
                        grid[y][x] = i
                        solve(grid)
                        grid[y][x] = 0
                return grid
    print("The result print: ")
    print_grid(grid)
    return grid
                

# I use this function to print my grid into console
def print_grid(grid):
    for i in range(9):
        if(i % 3 == 0 and i != 0):
            print("- - - - - - - - - - - -")
        for j in range(9):
            if j % 3 == 0 and j != 0:
                print(" | ", end="")
            if j == 8:
                print(str(grid[i][j]))
            else:
                print(str(grid[i][j]) + " ", end="")
    print('\n')
```

gui.py

```
grid = [
    [7, 8, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
    [6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 0, 9],
    [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 7, 8],
    [0, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 2, 6, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 9, 3, 0],
    [9, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 5],
    [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
    [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4, 0, 0],
    [0, 4, 9, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0, 7]
]
def solve_sudoku():
    global grid

    print("before: ")
    solver.print_grid(grid)

    grid = solver.solve(grid)

    print("after: ")
    solver.print_grid(grid)

def main():

    while run_program:
        # I do some pygame event check here

        # This is the part where I call solve_sudoku function
        if mouse_clicked:
            if 200 <= xmouse <= 320 and 550 <= ymouse <= 610:
                solve_sudoku()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the output: (Basically the grid changes in solver.py but stays same in gui.py)

before:

7 8 0  | 4 0 0  | 1 2 0

6 0 0  | 0 7 5  | 0 0 9

0 0 0  | 6 0 1  | 0 7 8

---

0 0 7  | 0 4 0  | 2 6 0

0 0 1  | 0 5 0  | 9 3 0

9 0 4  | 0 6 0  | 0 0 5

---

0 7 0  | 3 0 0  | 0 1 2

1 2 0  | 0 0 7  | 4 0 0

0 4 9  | 2 0 6  | 0 0 7

The result print:

7 8 5  | 4 3 9  | 1 2 6

6 1 2  | 8 7 5  | 3 4 9

4 9 3  | 6 2 1  | 5 7 8

---

8 5 7  | 9 4 3  | 2 6 1

2 6 1  | 7 5 8  | 9 3 4

9 3 4  | 1 6 2  | 7 8 5

---

5 7 8  | 3 9 4  | 6 1 2

1 2 6  | 5 8 7  | 4 9 3

3 4 9  | 2 1 6  | 8 5 7

after:

7 8 0  | 4 0 0  | 1 2 0

6 0 0  | 0 7 5  | 0 0 9

0 0 0  | 6 0 1  | 0 7 8

---

0 0 7  | 0 4 0  | 2 6 0

0 0 1  | 0 5 0  | 9 3 0

9 0 4  | 0 6 0  | 0 0 5

---

0 7 0  | 3 0 0  | 0 1 2

1 2 0  | 0 0 7  | 4 0 0

0 4 9  | 2 0 6  | 0 0 7

Comment: i think it'll be just simpler to pass `grid` as param to `solve_sudoku`, do your operation and return the `grid` value again, and replace it in outer scope

Comment: I totally agree with @Anonymous, but if you still want to do it this way: your code works for me, grid is modified in solve_sudoku(). Maybe you can show more of your code, with the prints you're doing (and where) ?

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it works fine.  Is it possible that you did not call solve_sudoko() before printing your grid? Here is how I tested it. My solve() function is in a different file called solver. It does not mutate the grid. In this case, it just appends the word "new" to the list. When I import it and call it with your code, it prints the new grid.

```
#code inside solver.py
def solve(grid):
    copy = list(grid)
    copy.append("new")
    return copy

#code inside main file
import solver
grid = [1,2,3]

def solve_sudoko():
    global grid
    grid = solver.solve(grid)

solve_sudoko()
print(grid)
#output: [1, 2, 3, 'new']
```

Comment: So I have edited my question above. I believe i did the same thing, but problem still exists..

Comment: I general you want to minimize the use of global variables in your code because of problems that are difficult to detect.  Try passing the grid as an argument to solve_sudoko(grid) and get rid of the global grid statement.